# Slack: search doesn't reveal bot/app messages

Tags: slack

It is a pain to find bot/app (messages w/ APP badge in title) messages. Standard search box doesn't show any of them. Is there any way for actual user (consumer of bot/app) to find such messages posted in the channel?

Answer (score 8):

Yes - this is available via the Slack search UI, but only after you've performed a search already.

Under the `Search Results` sidebar, look for the `Include:` subheading. Click on it and check the box labeled `Include messages from integrations & bots` to update your search and include messages from `APP`/bot users.

[image: Slack search results screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your response, indeed I can see them in search results, however I need to filter/search messages by user title. You know, that in messages API you can specify user and avatar, so that bot message looks like actual person typed it (except APP label on the gray background after user name). e.g. bot that reports what user does in separate system. So it would be nice to have an ability to find out what that person did lastly not by calling bot but using standard slack tools.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to search for a specific app, but doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. Instead of filtering it to messages from a specific user using the @name, you can type the name of the app.

```
in:#your-slack-channel from:"an amazing app" after:2020-06-30 before:2020-08-01
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. However it would not help me. In my case App produces messages that looks like person's message. It has an original person avatar and name, which are actual at that time. And people in channel struggles to find latest message that was "impersonated" by certain person. For e.g. people track sick leaves and out of office days in separate web-app, which has such slack integration. So for e.g. people would like to know which activities for e.g. Peter had tracked in last week.

Answer (score 1):

In slack App,you can include bot results using the Hide app and bit results in more options which is displayed after you have done a search as shown below.

[image: Search Search results Page]